# Concurrent execution of Cassandra prepared statement returns invalid JSON as result

Tags: c#, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax

When I use prepared statement for async execution of multiple statements I get JSON with broken data. Keys and values got totally corrupted.

First I encoutered this issue when I were performing stress testing of our project using custom script. We are using DataStax C++ driver and execute statements from different fibers.

Then I was trying to isolate problem and wrote simple C# program which starts multiple Tasks in a loop. Each task uses the once created prepared statement to read data from the base. For some rows result is totally mess, eg:

**Expected** (fetched by cqlsh)

```
516b00a2-01a7-11e6-8630-c04f49e62c6b |  
lucid_lynx_value_45404 | 
precise_pangolin_value_618429 | 
saucy_salamander_value_302796 |    
trusty_tahr_value_873 | 
vivid_vervet_value_216045 | 
wily_werewolf_value_271991
```

**Actual**

```js
{
    "sa": "516b00a2-01a7-11e6-8630-c04f49e62c6b", 
    "lucid_lynx": "wily_werewolflue_45404", 
    "precise_pangolin": "precise_pangolin_value_618429", 
    "saucy_salamander": "saucy_salamander_value_302796", 
    "trusty_tahr": "trusty_tahr_value_873", 
    "vivid_vervet": "vivid_vervet_value_216045", 
    "wily_werewolf": "wily_werewolf_value_271991"
}
```

Here is the main part of C# code.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  const int task_count = 300;

  using(var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints(/*contact points here*/).Build())
  {
    using(var session = cluster.Connect())
    {
      var prepared = session.Prepare("select json * from test_neptunao.ubuntu where id=?");
      var tasks = new Task[task_count];
      for(int i = 0; i < task_count; i++)
      {
        tasks[i] = Query(prepared, session);
      }
      Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private static Task Query(PreparedStatement prepared, ISession session)
{
  string id = GetIdOfRandomRow();
  var stmt = prepared.Bind(id);
  stmt.SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.One);
  return session.ExecuteAsync(stmt).ContinueWith(tr =>
  {
    foreach(var row in tr.Result)
    {
      var value = row.GetValue<string>(0);
      //some kind of output
    }
  });
}
```

CQL script with test DB schema.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test_neptunao
WITH replication = {
    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
    'replication_factor' : 3
};

use test_neptunao;

create table if not exists ubuntu (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    precise_pangolin text,
    trusty_tahr text,
    wily_werewolf text, 
    vivid_vervet text,
    saucy_salamander text,
    lucid_lynx text
);
```

**UPD**

Expected JSON

```js
{
    "id": "516b00a2-01a7-11e6-8630-c04f49e62c6b", 
    "lucid_lynx": "lucid_lynx_value_45404", 
    "precise_pangolin": "precise_pangolin_value_618429", 
    "saucy_salamander": "saucy_salamander_value_302796", 
    "trusty_tahr": "trusty_tahr_value_873", 
    "vivid_vervet": "vivid_vervet_value_216045", 
    "wily_werewolf": "wily_werewolf_value_271991"
}
```

**UPD2**

Here is the [sample c# project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwa5_5U6U7PFRnFxemdFTWkyNG8/view?usp=sharing) mentioned above

**UPD3**

The issue was resolved after upgrading to Cassandra 3.5.

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing to output the results in the C# code? (i.e. where you have the comment "//some kind of output")

Comment: @LukeTillman just Console.WriteLine() under a lock. I updated the answer with link to the sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're seeing [CASSANDRA-11048](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11048) (JSON Queries are not thread safe).  Upgrading Cassandra to a version with the fix is the best way to resolve this.

Comment: It started working after upgrading to Cassandra 3.5, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only error I see in the generated JSON is the name of the primary key which should be **"id"** instead of **"sa"**. Otherwise the other columns are correct.

```
{
    "sa": "516b00a2-01a7-11e6-8630-c04f49e62c6b", 
    "lucid_lynx": "wily_werewolflue_45404", 
    "precise_pangolin": "precise_pangolin_value_618429", 
    "saucy_salamander": "saucy_salamander_value_302796", 
    "trusty_tahr": "trusty_tahr_value_873", 
    "vivid_vervet": "vivid_vervet_value_216045", 
    "wily_werewolf": "wily_werewolf_value_271991"
}
```

What kind of JSON structure did you expect to get as result ?

Comment: Indeed there is a bug, you can open a JIRA for the core Cassandra team to fix it

Comment: **"sa"** instead of **"id"** and **"wily_werewolflue_45404"** instead of **"lucid_lynx_value_45404"**. Also updated the question with this info.

Comment: I wonder if there is some concurrency thing going on here with not collecting result set futures?